# Write a function that finds the top 5 max values in array of structures?

Tags: c, arrays, structure

Find the top 5 maximum values in array of structures (for C programming)?
I have an array of structures as follows:

```
struct info {
char name[100];
int number;
}
struct info people[10]
```

In char name[100] are names of people (up to 10) and they have a corresponding value in int balance:

```
Jane 10
John 40
Harry 16
Eva -5
...
```

until it gets to 10 people.
How do I find and print the 5 people who have the highest numbers?
i.e:

```
John 40
Harry 16
Jane 10
...
```

I have tried the following code:

```
int i,j, k=5, max, temp;
//move maximum 5 numbers to the front of the array
for (i=0; i<k; i++) {
    max=i;
for (j=i+1; j<10; j++) {
    if (people[i].number>people[max].number) {
        max=j;
    }
}
//swap numbers
temp=people[i].number;
people[i].number=people[max].number;
people[max].number=temp;

//swap names to match swapped numbers so they correspond
temp=people[i].name;
people[i].name=people[max].name;
people[max]=temp;
}
for (i=0; i<k; i++) {
    printf("%s  %d\n", people[i].name, people[i].number);
}
```

However, I get an error message on the second swap since its char type. How should I fix this or what else would work for this objective?

Comment: You copy strings using the `strcpy` family of functions.

Comment: Why swap structures around?  Simply find the five indices that correspond to the five elements of the array with the largest values.    Remember to allow for possibility of duplicate values.

Comment: `struct info temp = people[i]; people[i] = people[max]; people[max] = temp;`

Comment: Sort using this example.. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/97555/

Comment: @4py - not very helpful to a `c` programmer :(

Comment: @KevinDTimm, Yea! I missed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from OP's code, just swap the structure.  [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371480/write-a-function-that-finds-the-top-5-max-values-in-array-of-structures/43380527#comment73805252_43371480). Only a small changed needed for OP's code.

Arrays can not be copied with assignments but *objects*, like `struct info` can be assigned.

```
int i, j, k=5;

//move maximum `k` numbers to the front of the array
for (i=0; i<k; i++) {
  int max=i;
  for (j=i+1; j<10; j++) {
    if (people[i].number > people[max].number) {
      max=j;
    }
  }
  //swap info
  struct info temp = people[i];
  people[i] = people[max];
  people[max] = temp;
}

for (i=0; i<k; i++) {
  printf("%s  %d\n", people[i].name, people[i].number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the array and then take the 5 first/last (depending on the sort order) entries of the sorted array.

1st define a compare function:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for qsort() */
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf() */


struct info
{
  char name[100];
  int number;
};

int cmp_struct_info_desc(const void * pv1, const void * pv2)
{
  const struct info * pi1 = pv1;
  const struct info * pi2 = pv2;

  return pi2->number - pi1->number;
}
```

2ndly use the [Standard C function `qsort()`](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.22.5.2).

```
struct info people[] =  {
  ... /* initialise array people here ... */
}

int main(void)
{
  size_t number_of_array_elements = sizeof people/sizeof *people;

  qsort(people, number_of_array_elements, sizeof *people, cmp_struct_info_desc);

  for (size_t s = 0; s < number_of_array_elements; ++s)
  {
    printf("%zu. = {%d, '%s'}\n", s, people[s].number, people[s].name);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I meant. Plussed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most general way would probably be to first sort the `people` array. Once this is done just pick the first five elements.

Comment: This is only the easiest way if you use existing functions for sorting... Otherwise, if programmed from scratch, scanning through the array and remembering the top-5-indices is easier to code.

Comment: Shouldn't he use existing functions?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to sort the array people based on the number attribute iso individual swaps.

If you want to go ahead with current approach use strcpy functions iso "=" operator for name

Answer (score 0):

Rather than keeping track of 5 out of total 10 indices, sorting seems better to me.
You can use qsort to sort the 10 elements and then pick the top 5.

```
 int cmp(void *a,void *b)
 {
   struct info as=*((struct info*)a);
   struct info bs=*((struct info*)b)
   return bs.number-as.number;  //sorting in descending order
 }
```

and then

```
    qsort(people,10,sizeof people[0],cmp);
```